# How to retrieve documents where a field is maximum for every other distinct field on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, document

I have the following collection on MongoDB (I've omitted the field `_id` for clarity):

```
[
  {
    "stock": "Stock1",
    "value": 12,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock1",
    "value": 13,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock1",
    "value": 14,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock1",
    "value": 15,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock2",
    "value": 6,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock2",
    "value": 5,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2019
  }
]
```

And I wish to retrieve the documents for each `stock` with the latest (maximum) `year` available, such that I end up with the following:

```
[
  {
    "stock": "Stock1",
    "value": 14,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock1",
    "value": 15,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock2",
    "value": 6,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "stock": "Stock2",
    "value": 5,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2019
  }
]
```

I'm tempted to programmatically loop over each `stock` and in a first step query the last `year` with `find({"stock": "Stockx"}).sort({"year": -1}).limit(1)` and in a second step query `find({"stock": "Stockx", "year": maxyearforStockx"})`. Is there a more elegant way of doing this with the `find` or `aggregate` commands?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$sort` - Sort by `year` descending.
2. `$group` - Group by `stock` and `year`.
3. `$group` - Group by `stock` and take the first item of `stockYearItems` (from 2).
4. `$unwind` - Descontruct `items.stockYearItems` array to multiple documents.
5. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document with new document to show `stock` documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$sort": {
    "year": -1
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      "stock": "$stock",
      "year": "$year"
    },
    stockYearItems: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.stock",
    items: {
      $first: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$items.stockYearItems"
},
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$items.stockYearItems"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8x4c3OE83yR)